# Set ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode conditionally

Tags: windows-xp, inno-setup

I use `ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode=x64` and it works fine on 64-bit Vista/Win7, but on XP x64 it causes problems (regserver fails), so I want to set it only if the OS is not XP x64.

Is that possible?

Comment: Don't you rather try to use the [`RegisterServer`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_registerserver) function like this way (the first parameter determines, if the DLL/OCX should be registered as 64-bit) `RegisterServer(GetWindowsVersion >= $06000000, ...);` ?

Comment: Forgot to admit, it's not possible to conditionally set the `ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode` directive value.

Comment: Just saw your profile. Are you really one of the Inno Setup devs? Thanks so much for taking the time to answer this question. Anyway, could you post it as an answer then, so I can accept it?

Comment: No, I'm not :-) That insider means just that I know InnoSetup internals pretty well (I've built many custom versions several times).

Comment: @TLama: Out of interest, are you on the Inno newsgroups?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to conditionally set the [`ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_architecturesinstallin64bitmode) directive nor decide if you want to run the setup in 32-bit or 64-bit install mode from script in any way (even [`ArchitecturesAllowed`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_architecturesallowed) cannot be conditionally set). What I'd suggest as a workaround for your problem is to use the [`RegisterServer`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_registerserver) function from code passing to its first parameter condition returning True when you'll be on 64-bit Vista above system. Using the code from the reference, it may looks like this (the following pseudocode should register the OCX extension as 64-bit only on 64-bit systems with Windows Vista above):

```
RegisterServer(IsWin64 and (GetWindowsVersion >= $06000000), 
  ExpandConstant('{sys}\hhctrl.ocx'), False);
```